# MySQL return only the first transaction between dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table to keep every transaction from clients,

is it possible to retrieve only the first transaction a client did between 2018-10-01 and 2018-12-31

Example:

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name |    transactions     |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 | abc  | 2018-10-04 17:34:24 |
|  2 | xyz  | 2018-11-09 17:34:24 |
|  3 | xyz  | 2018-12-05 17:34:24 |
|  4 | abc  | 2018-12-11 17:34:24 |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

I would like to get only:

```
abc - 2018-10-04 17:34:24
xyz - 2018-11-09 17:34:24
```

is that posible?

Comment: Not sure what you want here... i assume you want to select the records `1 - abc - 2018-10-04 17:34:24` and `2 - xyz - 2018-11-09 17:34:24` ? Because those are the "first" records of the clients..

Comment: Hi Raymond thank you for your reply, yes that's right, I would like to get only the first records

Comment: That duplication link wil not work in this case @Barmar it will not handle ties

Comment: @RaymondNijland You can first minimize the date then minimize the ID within that.

Comment: @Barmar I'm going through the post and I'm not sure I understand what how should I minimise the date value, would appreciate if you could give me a hint on the query, thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure how I can give you just a hint. I took pity and wrote the query in an answer, even though it's just like the queries in the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the patterns in [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?noredirect=1&lq=1) except use `MIN()` instead of `MAX()`. And add a `BETWEEN` condition to restrict the time period.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT name, MIN(transactions) AS minTransactions
      FROM yourTable
      WHERE transactions BETWEEN '2018-10-01' and '2018-12-31 23:59:59'
      GROUP BY name) AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.transactions = t2.minTransactions
```